# How to detect overlay window has been hidden in Android 12

Tags: android, android-12

One of the major changes in Android 12 is [**App Overlay Controls**](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/features#hide-application-overlay-windows).

This feature allows you to hide the overlay window (window type is **TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY**).
The details are summarized very clearly in [this article](https://buraksinankarabulut.medium.com/android-12-app-overlay-controls-d9a568b31d4d).
I think it is a very innovative feature.

However, there is one thing I am having trouble with this feature.

I don't know how to detect that the overlay window itself is hidden.

I've created a sample that shows the overlay window and an app that hides the overlay, and I've tested the various callbacks that the overlay window receives, but I couldn't detected that the overlay window itself is hidden.

If anyone has a solution, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find an answer? Can you show how you are trying to show overlay window from another app